# Using the inner product to determine the components of a vector under a different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, quantum-mechanics, change-of-basis

**Context.** I was recently reading a passage from a book on Quantum Mechanics where the author discusses a technique to determine the components of a vector in terms of an alternate basis.  The technique seems to be, for vector $|f\rangle$ and basis elements $|k\rangle$ and $|x\rangle$ (from two distinct basis sets), that the way to find the $|k\rangle$ component of $|f\rangle$ in terms of the $|k\rangle$ basis is to compute

$$
\langle k|f \rangle
$$

and likewise for

$$
\langle x|f \rangle
$$

Here is the fuller context from page 68 of *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*:

> [image]

**Problem:** When I try to apply this general pattern against a simpler vector space example, I don't get the answer I expect.

**Example setup.**

- Suppose we're operating in the $\mathbb{R}^2(\mathbb{R})$ vector space.
- Let us denote by $e_i$ the standard basis.  That is, $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1)$.
- Let us denote by $d_i$ the "diagonal" basis, with $d_1 = (1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$ and $d_2 = (-1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$ (but note here I'm denoting these alternative basis elements in the original $e_i$ basis!).
- Let $\vec{v} = (-1, -1)$ (again in terms of the standard $e_i$ basis).

**Setting up some inner product calculations.** Let our inner product be the standard dot product. Since both $e_i$ and $d_i$ are orthogonal bases, the formula

$$
\langle v | w \rangle = \sum_i v_i w_i
$$

holds under both bases.

**Inner products in terms of the $e_i$ basis.**

1. $\langle d_1 | v \rangle = (1/\sqrt{2}*-1) + (1/\sqrt{2}*-1) = -\sqrt{2}$
2. $\langle e_1 | v \rangle = (1*-1) + (0*-1) = -1$
3. $\langle d_2 | v \rangle = (-1/\sqrt{2}*-1) + (1/\sqrt{2}*-1) = 0$
4. $\langle e_2 | v \rangle = (0*-1) + (1*-1) = -1$

**Inner products in terms of the $d_i$ basis.**  Under this new basis I'm assuming that $|d_1\rangle = (1, 0)$, $|d_2\rangle = (0, 1)$, $|e_1\rangle = (1, -1)$, $|e_2\rangle = (1, 1)$, and $|v\rangle = (-\sqrt{2}, 0)$:

1. $\langle d_1 | v \rangle = (1*-\sqrt{2}) + (0*0) = -\sqrt{2}$
2. $\langle e_1 | v \rangle = (1*-\sqrt{2}) + (-1*0) = -\sqrt{2}$
3. $\langle d_2 | v \rangle = (0*-\sqrt{2}) + (1*0) = 0$
4. $\langle e_2 | v \rangle = (1*-\sqrt{2}) + (1*0) = -\sqrt{2}$

**Result.** When operating under the standard basis,

$$
(\langle d_1 | v \rangle, \langle d_2 | v \rangle) = (-\sqrt{2}, 0)
$$

as desired. But when operating under the diagonal basis

$$
(\langle e_1 | v \rangle, \langle e_2 | v \rangle) = (-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}) \ne (-1, -1)
$$

I am able to go from $e_i$ to $d_i$ but not from $d_i$ to $e_i$.

Comment: Why did you fail to normalize the vectors of the d basis? You shouldn't have any problems if you did that (i.e. divided your $d_i$s by $\sqrt 2$).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I adjusted my answer per your comment.  I am now able to go from the standard basis to the diagonal basis, but not vice versa.  Do you know what my mistake might be?

Comment: BUT you didn't normalize the *e*s in the new basis! Write down the 2x2 matrix transforming bases, and al should be clear. The important thing to see is that $ {\mathbb 1}= |e_1\rangle \langle e_1| +  |e_2\rangle \langle e_2|=  |d_1\rangle \langle d_1| +  |d_2\rangle \langle d_2| $.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos: I'm having trouble understanding how e.g. $e_1 = (1, 1)$ isn't normalized under the diagonal baisis since (1,1) will carve out an isosceles triangle with two sides equal to $1/sqrt{2}$ (each corresponding to a component of 1 for each dimension), with the base of the triangle having length 1 (hence normalized?). I know I'm mistake here, but trying to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, and I fear you are misreading the text you are quoting. Changing basis amounts to going from the *x*-basis to the *k*-basis, which you wisely chose to replicate/parallel on your  $\mathbb{R}^2(\mathbb{R})$ vector space.

The normalized *x*-basis is then simulated by  $|e_1\rangle = (1, 0)^T$ and $|e_2\rangle = (0, 1)^T$. The *k*-basis  is  simulated by   $|d_1\rangle = (1, 1 )^T/\sqrt{2}$ and $|d_2\rangle = (-1, 1)/\sqrt{2}$. The quantum state $|f\rangle$ is simulated by $|\vec{v}\rangle = -(1, 1)^T=-\sqrt{2} |d_1\rangle  $.

To change basis from *x* to *k*, as in your (1.10.34), you utilize the (orthogonal; in QM it is unitary) transformation matrix *T*,
$$
|d_i\rangle = |e_1\rangle \langle  e_1    |d_i\rangle + |e_2\rangle \langle  e_2 |d_i\rangle  = \sum_j T_{ij} |e_j\rangle, \\  T_{ij}=\langle e_j|d_i\rangle, \\
|\vec d\rangle \langle \vec e|= {\mathbb T}= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}/\sqrt{2},  \tag{1}
$$
where ${\mathbb T}^{-1} =  {\mathbb T}^{T}$ taking you back from the *d* to the *e* basis.

Importantly, the two bases are complete, so, as above, (and in your text, where their continuous analogs are inserted),
$$
{\mathbb I}= |e_1\rangle \langle e_1|+ |e_2\rangle \langle e_2| = |d_1\rangle \langle d_1| + |d_2\rangle \langle d_2|.  \tag{2}
$$

You may now compute the "wavefunctions",
$$
\langle e_i|\vec v\rangle = -(1,1)^T \\  \langle d_i|\vec v\rangle =   \sum_j \langle d_i|e_j\rangle \langle e_j|\vec v\rangle   = - \sqrt{2} \delta_{i1}.   \tag{3}
$$

I've no idea what the latter part of your questions purports to be doing. The bases' relation is valid for all representations. You *already* changed bases. This generalizes naturally to QM.